# Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS update mysql version 5.7.23 to 5.7.26

Tags: mysql

How I can update mysql 5.7.23 to 5.7.26 ?

Comment: Your Ubuntu should be at 16.04.6 (not 16.04.5) so it could be you haven't fully-upgraded your system (ie. `sudo apt dist-upgrade` or `sudo apt full-upgrade`).  If you do that you may find your system upgrades as you wish (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=mysql)

Comment: I can't upgrade the linux version, there isn't other way to just upgrate mysql to 5.7.26 ?

Comment: Your Ubuntu 16.04 should have upgraded to 16.04.6 on or just before 28-Feb-2019, so if it reports 16.04.5 it could mean you haven't fully upgraded your system since before then, or you have held-packages stopping upgrade, which could be stopping your mysql upgrades too.  You should fully-upgrade your 16.04 LTS system (as 16.04.6 is the current fully upgraded 16.04).

Comment: So after a full-upgrade I should have the 5.7.26 mysql version ? PS, seem to work, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't fully upgraded your 16.04 LTS system.

Your Ubuntu 16.04 should have reported 16.04.6 on or after 28-Feb-2019, however by not fully-upgrading your release, you're behind on updates.

The packages of `mysql` shown with https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=mysql show 5.7.26 is the current used by a fully-upgraded Ubuntu 16.04 system.

Your need to `sudo apt full-upgrade`